# how to send mail through another mail server on linux

Tags: email

I am trying to use `mailx` command but due to firewall it's not working. I tried using `mailx` on terminal but its giving warnings, as follow:

```
send-mail: warning: inet_protocols: IPv6 support is disabled: Address family not supported by protocol
send-mail: warning: inet_protocols: configuring for IPv4 support only
postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: IPv6 support is disabled: Address family not supported by protocol
postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: configuring for IPv4 support only
```

Comment: Which distro are you on and what is the end goal you wish to achieve?

Comment: I want to design a script that send mail containing another script to multi ple server

Comment: Not necessary that it is the firewall. Did you configure the mailserver on your server to send mails to server the other mailserver? What mailserver did you install? sendmail? postfix? The warning you get is because you do not have IPv6. Look for a parameter like inet_protocols and set it to ipv4 instead of all.

Comment: actually it is task given to me and I don't know how to set its parameter..i tried to configure /etc/postfix/main.cf but not working as expected..I am totally confused